# What is the easiest mode to get back Firebase token in this async task?

Tags: java, android

I need to modify an 8 year old, very bound code. In the old code I didn't have to wait for the async result, so I could work with it easily, but now I have to wait for it because of another async task.

Old version:

```
public class AsyncGetToken extends MyAsyncTask {

    public AsyncGetToken(Context context, TaskResponseListener taskResponseListener, String message) {
        super(context, taskResponseListener, message);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response executeTask(JSONObject json) throws Exception {
        if (FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() == null) {
            sendErrorResponse(new Error(getType(), ERR_CODE, ERR_LOG));
            return null;
        }
        return new Response(getFunction(), id, FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(), null);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getFunction() {
        return ASYNC_FUNC;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getType() {
        return ASYNC_TYPE;
    }
}
```

New version:

```
public class AsyncGetToken extends MyAsyncTask {

    public AsyncGetToken(Context context, TaskResponseListener taskResponseListener, String message) {
        super(context, taskResponseListener, message);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response executeTask(JSONObject json) throws Exception {
       FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                        // Get new FCM registration token
                        String token = task.getResult();
                        //now i have to return a new Response with the token but obviously I can't send it back
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected String getFunction() {
        return ASYNC_FUNC;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getType() {
        return ASYNC_TYPE;
    }
}
```

So what's the easiest way?

Comment: Have you tried to make return new Response below the String token?